# How to connect to a remote server using nsISocketTransportService in a firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I need to connect to a remote server (listening on port 9442) in my firefox extension. I'm using `nsISocketTransportService` and my problem is how to listen to `dataAvailable` event? I search through mozilla docs but could find anything useful. My question is how can i listen for the data when i connect to a remote server using `nsISocketTransportService.createTransport()`? Is there any other way to connect to a remote TCP server?

```js
var socket = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"]
                          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsISocketTransportService)
                          .createTransport(null, 0, host, port, null);

var poolOutputStream = socket.openOutputStream(0, 0, 0);

var helloMessage = JSON.stringify({type: 'hello', clientID: currentClientID});
    poolOutputStream.write(helloMessage, helloMessage.length);

var poolRawInputStream = socket.openInputStream(0, 0, 0);
var poolInputStream = Components.classes ["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream)
                        .init(poolRawInputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`NetUtil` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm):

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

NetUtil.asyncFetch(poolRawInputStream, function(stream, result)
{
  if (!Components.isSuccessCode(result))
  {
    // Error handling here
  }

  var data = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(stream, inputStream.available());
  ...
});
```

The disadvantage of this approach: `NetUtil` will first read all the data into memory, your callback will not be called until the stream is closed. If you want to get the data as it comes in you will have to use `nsIInputStreamPump` directly:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

var pump = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/input-stream-pump;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIInputStreamPump);
pump.init(poolRawInputStream, -1, -1, 0, 0, true);

var listener = {
  onStartRequest: function(request, context) {},
  onDataAvailable: function(request, context, stream, offset, count)
  {
    var data = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(stream, count);
    ...
  },
  onStopRequest: function(request, context, result)
  {
    if (!Components.isSuccessCode(result))
    {
      // Error handling here
    }
  }
};

pump.asyncRead(listener, null);
```

Comment: `nsIInputStreamPump` is exactly what i needed, i will test your code as soon as possible and be back with results. thank you Wladimir